# Decompression in andriod is not working which is compressed using php

Tags: php, android, compression

I have compressed a String in PHP using the following function

```
      ...........................................
      $compressedStr= gzcompress($txt, 9);
      ...........................................
```

and send the compressed results using QR code to the android . In android the received string was compressed in android using the following function but this is not working.What will be best way to compress a string in php and then decompress in java in android?

```
public static String DecompressString(String inputStr) throws Exception {

    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    DeflaterOutputStream dos = new DeflaterOutputStream(baos);
    dos.write(inputStr.getBytes());
    dos.flush();
    dos.close();
    ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray());
    InflaterInputStream iis = new InflaterInputStream(bais);

    String result = "";
    byte[] buf = new byte[5];
    int rlen = -1;
    while ((rlen = iis.read(buf)) != -1) {
        result += new String(Arrays.copyOf(buf, rlen));
    }

        return  result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The documentation is not clear, but it appears that `InflaterInputStream` invokes `nowrap` in the `Inflater` class, so it is expecting the raw deflate format. `gzcompress()` delivers a zlib-wrapped deflate stream. You could use the `Inflater` class directly, or `gzdeflate()` on the PHP end.